# Symfony and SwiftMailer sending with starttls

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, starttls

Can someone explain to me how work SSL AND STARTTLS with PHP ?

Il have a dedicated server with Postfix and Dovecot (managed by plesk). I don't have SSL.

To get and send my emails, I use SMTP/IMAP with STARTTLS.

But in PHP, with Swiftmailer and Symfony, I only have two options : ssl or tls. 
None of the 2 work in my case, emails do not leave.

Searching on stackoverflow, I put this in my code and this working :

```
$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.server.fr', 587, 'tls')
->setUsername($username)
->setPassword($password)
->setStreamOptions(array('ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
 )));

$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

Do you think my configuration is correct?

Comment: I think it's correct, try to export you config in Ressource and parse them with YamlParser. @see the difference between START TLS AND SSL / TLS  here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540374/starttls-vs-ssl-tls

Answer (score 2):

The port `587` you provided indicates, that the option `tls` is correct. So to get it working in Symfony with Swiftmailer, you don't need to instantiate a new `SmtpTransport`.

Simply add the following to your Swiftmailer Configuration `config.yml`:

```
Swiftmailer
    # here are some other swiftmailer options like host, user etc.
    stream-options:
        ssl:
            allow_self_signed : true
            verify_peer: false
```

Continue using swiftmailer as normal.