# Support for LDAP over SSL

Tags: ssl, ldap

How can I know that, my application (using LDAP/exchange server and  Exchange Web Service) supports LDAP over SSL?

I am new to this concept. I do not know the concept of SSL certificate too. Can any one explain me it in simple terms. Please reply as soon as possible. I need it to use.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution, here are the links...enjoy..

[verify LDAP over SSL](http://www.expta.com/2009/11/how-to-test-ldap-over-ssl-connections.html)

[Enable LDAP over SSL/ LDAPS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;321051)

Answer (score 0):

Your exchange admin needs to setup LDAPS which is the secure version of LDAP.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can we do that?

Comment: Alternatively to LDAPS, you can also use `STARTTLS` with LDAP on the same port: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660798/what-happens-on-the-wire-when-a-tls-ldap-or-tls-http-connection-is-set-up/3661416#3661416