# how to i SMTP with c# 4/.NET 4 to port 465/SSL (currently unsupported) ... need ideas

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ssl, .net-4.0, smtp

first, i've discovered through trial and error that c# 4/.NET 4 has some serious limitations which are to me unexplainable.

Microsoft is **not** supporting **SSL** over port **465** in c# 4/.NET 4.

Microsoft *only* supports **SSL** on **587** through **"STARTTLS"**.

i need to use **465/SSL** because my mail server hMailServer does not support "STARTTLS".

i had hoped to use c# 4/.NET 4 out of the box ... i do not want to purchase any third party solutions.

what i would like to do is to craft my own solution for **SMTP using SSL on port 465**.

i'm guessing that i may have to use c# unmanaged code to make this happen.

*any ideas?*, please & thank you.  rgds/gerry

References:

["configuring SSL confusion..."](http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=21650), hMailServer forum thread.

MSDN:  ["SmtpClient.EnableSsl Property"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx):
"An alternate connection method is where an SSL session is established up front before any protocol commands are sent. This connection method is sometimes called SMTP/SSL, SMTP over SSL, or SMTPS and by default uses port 465. This alternate connection method using SSL is not currently supported."

P.S.:  i searched SO and Google and can find nothing directly relevant.

Comment: STARTTLS > SMTP over SSL

Comment: @Joel, STARTTLS is for SMTP over SSL/TLS, after upgrade from plain SMTP, as opposed to SMTPS (which can also be called SMTP over SSL) where the TLS connection is established from the start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660798/what-happens-on-the-wire-when-a-tls-ldap-or-tls-http-connection-is-set-up/3661416#3661416

Answer (score 0):

As you already discovered MS says clearly that what you want is NOT supported "out-of-the-box".
AND you don't want to use any 3rd-party library.

Possibilities to accomodate both:

- you could implement the needed protocol (SMTPS) yourself (not recommended!) OR
- use some TCP tunneling mechanism/proxy (which in turn means again a 3rd-party library) OR
- you could switch from your current SMTP server (hMailServer) to one that supports `STARTTLS`

**EDIT - as per comments some libraries supporting "SMTP with implicitc SSL":**

- http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/ (commercial, for sample source see http://www.emailarchitect.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=21)
- http://www.atp-inc.net/component/mail.net/ (commercial)
- MS CDO (free, sample source see http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-asp-net-3-5-c-vb-book-isbn-978-0-470-18759-3/82795-sending-emails-port-465-a.html, NOT recommended!)
- http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-features.asp (commercial, sample source see http://www.example-code.com/csharp/gmail_smtp_465.asp)

Comment: although, preferably, i do not want to purchase any third party solutions, i'm willing to check them out and to also look into open source, so, yes, please do provide some links. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, and if it still works (*"This API is now obsolete"*), you should be able to use SMTPS (SMTP with up-front SSL/TLS) using [`System.Web.Mail.MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.aspx):

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage mailMsg = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
// ...
mailMsg.Fields.Add
            ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl",
                 true);
```

Of course, the fact that this API is now obsolete in .Net 4 is not ideal. It probably still works in practice.

Failing that, you may have to rely on 3rd-part libraries or something like [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/).

Comment: thank you ... i'm aware of the deprecated System.Web.Mail API; i'm uncomfortable at using anything where Microsoft could "pull the plug" at any time.

Comment: @gerryLowry, depending on how this needs to integrate with the rest of the system (in particular regarding licensing), running stunnel alongside your application should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can establish a ssl TCP/IP connection to your smtp server, generate proper commands and headers and send them throw it.
However, this would be too confusing. 
I have done it already in [Aegis Implicit Mail (AIM)] (https://sourceforge.net/projects/netimplicitssl/) project. Try to download it's source code and have a look.

You can find out the answer of all your problems [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/netimplicitssl/wiki/Home/)