# How to configure and enable SSL in PostgreSQL Database on new port?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I want to enable SSL for PostgreSQL DB.

I have generated certificates and Key also.

By trying multiple ways, I have enabled it on default port i.e 5432.

But I want to enable SSL on new port.

Please help me with exact working solution.

Comment: did you try changing port number in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: yes, but its not working. giving this error msg - 

An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
Connection timed out: connect

Details:
   Type: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException
   Error Code: 1114
   SQL State: 08001

Comment: consider sharing more research information and your work in a detailed manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL protocol uses the same port for plain-text and SSL/TLS connections.
(The upgrade is done on an existing connection [using an `SSLRequest` message](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/protocol-flow.html#id-1.10.6.7.12), part of PostgreSQL communication protocol. This is very similar to the use of [`STARTTLS` in other protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3661416/372643).)

As such, you can't really have one port listening to plain connections and another listening to SSL/TLS connections.

If you really want them on a different port, you could use a tool like [pgBouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#tls-settings) in front of your PostgreSQL server and configure it to handle the SSL/TLS settings.